# Messy complex integral

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

I want to solve this integral:

$\int_{0}^{2\pi}e^{\frac{-1}{e^{it}}}e^{it}$

When I plug it into Wolfram Alpha, the result is $-2\pi$.

However the indefinite integral is insane and it involves the exponential integral.

Is there any "simple" way to solve it?

I tried u-substitution and integrating by parts, but it's not making it any easier..

Comment: Do you not have $e^{it}/e^{it}$ here? Is this not the integral of $-1$?

Comment: .... I am so sorry, I don't know how I missed it. Thank you so much!

Comment: No need to apologize, I was just trying to verify that it wasn't a typo.

Comment: Now that I am writing it out, I am actually having difficulties "simplifying" it into $\frac{e^{it}}{e^{it}}$. I can get it to $\frac{e^{it}}{e^{\frac{1}{e^{it}}}}$ how do i proceed from here ?

Answer (score 2):

Here's a couple ways to see the answer:
$$
\int_0^{2 \pi} e^{-1/e^{it}} e^{it} dt = \int_0^{2 \pi} e^{-e^{-it}} e^{it} dt = \int_0^{2\pi}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n!} (-e^{-i t})^n e^{i t} dt
$$
which is pretty straightforward to integrate term by term, which you can do because the sum is uniformly convergent on a bounded interval.

Or, with a $u$-sub by defining $u = e^{-it}$:

$$
\int_0^{2 \pi} e^{-1/e^{it}} e^{it} dt = i \int_0^{2 \pi} \frac{e^{-e^{-it}}}{e^{-2 i t}} (-i) e^{-it} dt = i \oint_\gamma \frac{e^u}{u^2} du
$$

where $\gamma$ is a clockwise loop around the origin (in fact in this case it is the unit ring with clockwise orientation). This integral can be evaluated with Cauchy's integral formula.

Comment: is the last integral a contour integral ?

Comment: Yes. Technically, any integral of a complex-analytic function is a contour integral. When you do the $u$-sub, $e^{i 2\pi} = e^{i 0} = 1$, so the contour for $u$ is a closed loop. It goes clockwise because $e^{-i t}$ traverses the circle in the clockwise direction

Answer (score 1):

$\int_{0}^{2\pi}e^{\frac{-1}{e^{it}}}e^{it} dt=i \int_{0}^{2\pi}e^{\frac{-1}{e^{it}}}ie^{it} dt=i \int_{|z|=1}e^{\frac{-1}{z}} dz= i 2 \pi i Res(f; 0)=-2 \pi  Res(f; 0)$,

where $f(z)=e^{\frac{-1}{z}}$.

Since $f(z)=1- \frac{1}{z}+\frac{1}{2z^2}-+...$, we have $Res(f;0)=-1$, hence

$$\int_{0}^{2\pi}e^{\frac{-1}{e^{it}}}e^{it} dt=2 \pi.$$